# Adding placeholder to textfield on table view cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I made a text field on a table view cell. But I want to be able to add a placeholder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set textField placeHolder color progrmatically in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679075/set-textfield-placeholder-color-progrmatically-in-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField placeholder text overlay issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21368468/uitextfield-placeholder-text-overlay-issue)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Placeholder field in your Inspection panel as shown below. If you'd like to do that programmatically you can use the something similar to this

```
 //create the attribute dictionary
let placeholderAttr = [
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor(),
  NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 22.0)!,
]

//apply the attributes to the placeholder
yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "This is your placeholder text", attributes: placeholderAttr)
yourTextField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
```

[image: Inspection panel - Placeholder]